# Describing all solutions of $Ax=0$ in parametric vector form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, homogeneous-equation

I need clarification in understanding all solutions of $Ax=0$ in parametric vector form where the $A$ is row equivalent to the given matrix.

Matrix $A$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & -4 & -2 & 0 & 3 & -5 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &   -4 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   0 
\end{bmatrix}$$

The augmented matrix of $A$
$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cccccc|c}
 1 & -4 & -2 & 0 & 3 & -5 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1  & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &   -4  & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   0 & 0
    \end{array}
\right] $$

The Reduced Echelon Form $A$

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cccccc|c}
 1 & -4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1  & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &   -4  & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   0 & 0
    \end{array}
\right] $$

$x_1 = 4x_2 -9x_6 \\ x_2  is free \\ x_3 = 1x_6 \\ x_4  is free\\
x5 = 4x_6\\x_6  is free $

Which simplifies to

$x = $$\begin{bmatrix}
 x_1\\
 x_2\\
 x_3\\
 x_4\\
 x_5\\
 x_6 
\end{bmatrix}$ = $x_2$$\begin{bmatrix}
 4\\
 1\\
 0\\
 0\\
 0\\
 0 
\end{bmatrix}$ + 
$x_6$$\begin{bmatrix}
 -9\\
 0\\
 1\\
 0\\
 4\\
 1 
\end{bmatrix}$

Any help is appreciated! Please accept or reject the my solution to this equation and clarify mistakes (if any) that I have made.

Comment: check your reduced matrix again and try to write out that each x1,...,x6. You have a 3x6 matrix with a rank of only 2, so you should end up with a 4-parameter family of solutions!

Comment: @Alex Hey there, I just saw and corrected my matrix, how does it look now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is a $3x6$ matrix with $rank=3$. Then the solution should have $n-r=3-6=3$ parameters! All of your work is correct except for the answer. In the answer you provided $x_4=0$ for any given $x_2,x_6$. In reality, $x_4$ is a parameter that can take on ANY value and you can see from your reduced matrix that $x_4$ is completely independent from the other variables! Your final solution should be:

$x = $$\begin{bmatrix}
 x_1\\
 x_2\\
 x_3\\
 x_4\\
 x_5\\
 x_6 
\end{bmatrix}$ = $x_2$$\begin{bmatrix}
 4\\
 1\\
 0\\
 0\\
 0\\
 0 
\end{bmatrix}$ + 
$x_4$$\begin{bmatrix}
 0\\
 0\\
 0\\
 1\\
 0\\
 0 
\end{bmatrix}$+ 
$x_6$$\begin{bmatrix}
 -9\\
 0\\
 1\\
 0\\
 4\\
 1 
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I completely missed that! That really does help clarify things